# How can I generate a description based on 2 or 3 words in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 or 3 words and I want to get a 2 lines description based on these words
I am using javascript

I've been searching google for an API with some kind of AI to generate a description but I failed
and I hope that someone can help me with this.

here is an example:

title >> 3d sweet apple 
description >> sweet red apple modeled in high quality and ready for games, 3d printing and more

even something small like this would be great for me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wordsapi](https://www.wordsapi.com/#try) to get some relative expressions with the words you want.

But you probably have to write your own implementation about your problem anyway.

Comment: this is awesome i was just wondering if you know other apis that can have much more quality results not just the definition or synonyms

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is loop through the words you want to use, like "3d sweet apple" and use a

```
.includes()
```

function to find if if any description includes any of those words, and then return those descriptions. Hope this helps. I will attach a jsfiddle link as soon as I have it.

*edit - here is the code - NOT A JSFIDDLE LINK

```
//few words
var x = "sweet apple";
//description
var des = ["sweet apples are the very best fruits", "my name is bob"]
//descriptions that work
var ans = [];
//for loop with inlcudes
for(var i = 0; i < des.length; i++) {
  if(des[i].includes(x)) {
  ans.push(des[i]);
  }
}

//alerting the result
alert(ans);
```

Comment: you have miss understand me i have the title as an input and the description as an output

Comment: Yeah, but if its sweet apples, sweet apples (or sweet or apples) will be in your description. Then you can loop through your descriptions and show the ones that match. Or you can use an api and get some words that you want and do that.